# Apply algorithm on projection but retrieve information from original container

Tags: c++, range-v3

I would like to apply an algorithm on a projection of a container, but then use that information to retrieve information from the original container. In the contrived example below, I would like to use `iter` to find the related key-value pair in `my_vec`. I know there are simpler ways to solve this example in particular, but I would like to apply this to more complex projections.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <range/v3/algorithm/min_element.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/join.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/map.hpp>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> my_map{
        {"1", {500, 30}}, {"2", {20, 60}}, {"3", {14, 10}}, {"4", {5, 4}}, {"5", {30, 56}}};
    
    auto my_view = my_map | ranges::views::values | ranges::views::join | ranges::to_vector;
    auto iter    = ranges::min_element(my_view);

    for(const auto& val : my_view) { std::cout << val << ","; }
    std::cout << std::endl << *iter << "," << std::distance(my_view.begin(), iter) << std::endl;
}
```

Outputs:

```
5,4,20,60,30,56,14,10,500,30,
4,1
```

Comment: It's a pretty neat trick having duplicate keys in a `std::unordered_map`, like that. Are you sure the shown code does what you think it does?

Comment: Whoops, how embarrassing! Edited to fix the issue.

Comment: Looks like that you can simply pair each element with the original index, then extract it in the end.